# Google Places API issue with displaying name or type

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-places-api

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        function initialize() {
          var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete_search');
          var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
          autocomplete.setFields(['place_id', 'name', 'address_components', 'geometry', 'website', 'formatted_phone_number', 'type', 'name']);
          autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
            const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            const components = place.address_components;
            
            const website = place.website;
            $("#website").val(website);
            const type = place.type
            $("#type").val(type);
            const phonenumber = place.formatted_phone_number;
            $("#phonenumber").val(phonenumber);
            const locationname = place.name;
            $("$locationname").val(locationname)
        });
      }
```

Not able to get google places API to display name or type to their respective inputs after click. Does the JS look correct?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would help others try out your code in their own environment. We have no way of knowing how you were implementing those `divs` with the mentioned `IDs`. I also don't see `initialize()` callback in your `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=places"></script>`. Could this be the cause?